# Removing all columns summing to zero with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm currently working on a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
Site  Spp1  Spp2  Spp3  LOC  TYPE
S01   2     4     0     A    FLOOD
S02   4     0     0     A    REG
....
S10   0     1     0     B    FLOOD
S11   1     0     0     B    REG
```

What I'm trying to do is subset the dataframe so I can run some indicator species analysis in R.

The following code works in that I create two subsets of the data, merge them into one frame and then drop the unused factor levels

```
A.flood <- filter(data, TYPE == "FLOOD", LOC == "A")
B.flood <- filter(data, TYPE == "FLOOD", LOC == "B")
A.B.flood <- rbind(A.flood, B.flood) %>% droplevels.data.frame(A.B.flood, except = c("A", "B"))
```

What I was also hoping/need to do is to drop all `Spp` columns (in my real dataset there are ~ 60) that sum to zero. Is there a way to achieve this this with dplyr, and if there is, is it possible to pipe that code onto the existing `A.B.flood` dataframe code?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I managed to remove all the columns that summed to zero, by selecting only the columns that summed to > zero:

```
A.B.flood.subset <- A.B.flood[, apply(A.B.flood[1:(ncol(A.B.flood))], 2, sum)!=0]
```

Answer (score 13):

I realize this question is now quite old, but I came accross and found another solution using dplyr's "select" and "which", which might seem clearer to dplyr's enthusiasts:

```
A.B.flood.subset <- A.B.flood %>% select(which(!colSums(A.B.flood, na.rm=TRUE) %in% 0))
```

Comment: always great to have new solutions as questions come up again

Answer (score 6):

Without using any package, we can use `rowSums` of the 'Spp' columns (subset the columns using `grep`) and double negate so that rows with `sum>0` will be TRUE and others FALSE.  Use this index to subset the rows.

```
data[!!rowSums(data[grep('Spp', names(data))]),]
```

Or using `dplyr/magrittr`, we `select` the 'Spp' columns, get the `sum` of each row with `Reduce`, double negate and use `extract` from `magrittr` to subset the original dataset with the index derived.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
data %>%
    select(matches('^Spp')) %>%
    Reduce(`+`, .) %>%
    `!` %>%
    `!` %>%
     extract(data,.,)
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Site = c("S01", "S02", "S03", "S04"), 
Spp1 = c(2L, 
4L, 0L, 4L), Spp2 = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Spp3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L
), LOC = c("A", "A", "A", "A"), TYPE = c("FLOOD", "REG", 
"FLOOD", 
"REG")), .Names = c("Site", "Spp1", "Spp2", "Spp3", "LOC", 
"TYPE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. I actually got the title of my post wrong. I'm actually trying to sum the columns and not the rows. I've tried the first method `data[!!rowSums(data[grep('Spp', names(data))]),]` but replaced `rowSums` with `colSums`. This however causes a lot of new rows to appear which simply have NA in them.

Comment: @KaanKaant Can you please update your post with the expected output based on the data showed in my post?

Comment: I manged to solve the problem. I've edited the post with the details. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You should convert to tidy data with `tidyr::gather()` and the data frame will be much easier to manipulate.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
A.B.Flood %>% gather(Species, Sp.Count, -Site, -LOC, -TYPE) %>%
              group_by(Species) %>% 
              filter(Sp.Count > 0)
```

Voila, your tidy data minus the zero counts.

```
#    Site    LOC   TYPE Species Sp.Count
#  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>   <chr>    <int>
#1    S01      A  FLOOD    Spp1        2
#2    S02      A    REG    Spp1        4
#3    S11      B    REG    Spp1        1
#4    S01      A  FLOOD    Spp2        4
#5    S10      B  FLOOD    Spp2        1
```

Personally I'd keep it like this. If you want your original format back with the zero counts for the non-discarded species, just add `%>% spread(Species, Sp.Count, fill = 0)` to the pipeline.

```
#    Site    LOC   TYPE  Spp1  Spp2
#* <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    S01      A  FLOOD     2     4
#2    S02      A    REG     4     0
#3    S10      B  FLOOD     0     1
#4    S11      B    REG     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an even easier and quicker way to do this (and also more in line with your question: using dplyr).

```
A.B.flood.subset <- A.B.flood[, colSums(A.B.flood != 0) > 0]
```

or with a MWE:

```
df <- data.frame (x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100), z = rep(0, 100))
df[, colSums(df != 0) > 0]
```

Comment: What packages does it use? Can you give an explanation?

Comment: Doesn't require a package - that's base R. Avoiding the 'pipe' you can use: A.B.flood[, colSums(A.B.flood != 0) > 0]

Answer (score 2):

For those who want to use dplyr 1.0.0 with the `where` keyword, you can do:

```
A.B.flood %>% 
  select(where( ~ is.numeric(.x) && sum(.x) != 0))
```

returns:

```
  Spp1 Spp2
1    2    4
2    4    0
3    0    0
4    4    0
```

using the same data given by @akrun:

```
A.B.flood <- structure(
  list(
    Site = c("S01", "S02", "S03", "S04"),
    Spp1 = c(2L,
             4L, 0L, 4L),
    Spp2 = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
    Spp3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
    LOC = c("A", "A", "A", "A"),
    TYPE = c("FLOOD", "REG",
             "FLOOD",
             "REG")
  ),
  .Names = c("Site", "Spp1", "Spp2", "Spp3", "LOC",
             "TYPE"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```